# Date difference between two versions in SharePoint 2010 Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library which has an approval workflow, documents are changed and minor versions are created until the document is approved and then a major versions is created.

If rejected it will continue in minor versions. In short we can have 20 items in approval task list related to lets say from version 1 to version 2.

so what i need is a script that will query another list for each major version.

so far i'm getting all major versions and when these were created. Idea is to get date time difference between versions for one document and query the list where created is between two dates.

so far i have the following:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebURL="http://test/sites/PSMF"
$ModuleList = "Library"
#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

function GetMetadata {
    $list  = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ModuleList)
    $items = $list.items
     foreach($item in $items)
     {

        $versionHistory = $item.Versions

        foreach($version in $versionHistory)
        {
           #if major version 
           if($version.VersionLabel -match "[0-9]+.0")
           {
                $vNo = $version.VersionLabel
                $versioncreated = $version.created
                Write-Host " Version Created: $vNo" -ForegroundColor Green
                #get difference between two verisons?
                #pass two dates to fileter and return from GetApproval?
            }
        }
     }
 }


function GetApprovals($from, $To)
{
}

GetMetadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, I did not change how you are getting the items from your "ModuleList", but it is generally not safe to access the `Items` property directly on the `SPList` object unless you always know the list will have a small number of items.  Once the list grows beyond several hundred items, accessing that property will be significantly slower and cause performance degradation to other operations in your environment, and once your list grows beyond 5000 items, accessing that property will actually throw an error.
It is a best practice to always use `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery` with `SPList.GetItems()`, even if you are trying to get all items, as this allows your code to get items in chunks (or pages).  You can see how I am using it in the `GetApprovals` function, you just wouldn't need a query with a `Where` clause if you wanted to get all items.

This script should get you what you are looking for:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebURL="http://test/sites/PSMF"
$ModuleList = "Library"
$ApprovalListName = "PutNameOfApprovalListHere"
#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

function GetMetadata {
    $list  = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ModuleList)
    $items = $list.items

    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        $versionHistory = $item.Versions
        $prevVersionDate = $null

        foreach($version in $versionHistory)
        {
           #if major version 
           if($version.VersionLabel -match "[0-9]+.0")
           {
                $vNo = $version.VersionLabel
                $versioncreated = $version.created
                Write-Host " Version Created: $vNo" -ForegroundColor Green

                if ($prevVersionDate -ne $null)
                {
                    $approvals = GetApprovals -from $prevVersionDate -to $versioncreated
                    # do something with the approvals we just found?
                }

                $prevVersionDate = $versioncreated
            }
        }
    }
 }


function GetApprovals($from, $To)
{
    $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
    $spQuery.Query = '<Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' + $from + '</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' + $to + '</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query>'
    $spQuery.RowLimit = 200
    $approvalList = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ApprovalListName)
    $approvals = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]

    do
    {
        $approvalItems = $approvalList.GetItems($spquery)
        $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $approvalItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
        foreach($approvalItem in $approvalItems)
        {
            $approvals.Add($approvalItem);
        }    
    }while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

    return $approvals;
}

GetMetadata
```